# How to import React from global variable?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have a special scenario. One web application is built upon React. Another JavaScript utility is on React, but that utility is loaded by script tag. So, the application and the utility is built isolatedly. As a result, both the web application bundle file and utility bundle file have React built inside.

Now, we want to make them share one copy of React. It is preferred to export `React` as global variable in web application code(e.g. `global.React`) so that the utility can use it directly.

The code in utility is still like below. Hopefully, webpack can ignore it and import `React` from `global.React`.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

The question is: how to config webpack to tell the utiltiy not to bundle React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested with some non-React application:

- in index.html import React from CDN, this will define global `React`.

  `<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>`
- somewhere in application doing as below, resolves to React instance:

  `declare var React;`
  `console.log('React is ', React);`

So if your first bundle, registers `React` globally, you may use it.

Just keep in mind, that it considered as bad practice to import from global like this. It beats whole concept of `webpack`'s modularity. For instance, if your first module, upgrades to some backward incompatible version of `React`, your second module will break eventually as well.

For small projects, might be ok.